# Where does the database get initialized and how is it referenced, like a singleton?

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I'm trying to understand the play-slick code, and I'm interested to know where or how the database (dataSource) gets instantiated and is it a singleton?

I see its a plugin, so I'm guessing in the onStart the database is located in the config, and then it gets instantiated.

Then whenever we use DBAction, it re-uses that same instance.  But I can't seem to find where exactly that is in the codebase.

Could someone explain at a high level what is happening?  **I saw a reference to some kind of a Application context, is it saved there?**

**Is it using a pool?**

BTW, I know this a plugin (and it seems to be written by someone at typesafe) but it seems kind of unofficial, why isn't it in the typesafe repo somewhere?

Reference:

https://github.com/freekh/play-slick

Answer (score 0):

I believe play-slick uses the pool that  the Play Framework sets up. See the [Play documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/SettingsJDBC) and the external library that maintains the pool for Play, [BoneCP](http://jolbox.com/).